# updating old rspec syntax with stubs

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have some code i am following from a tutorial but i have run into problems now it is using stubs in terms of updating it to current rspec syntax. The code in question is relatively simple and taken from a teacher spec file. How would this bit of code be updated for the current syntax.

```
describe Teacher do 
    it "should store assignments" do
        student = stub
        assignment = stub
        subject.submit_assignment(student, assignment)
        expect(subject.assignment_for_student(student)).to eq(assignment)
    end
```

Comment: Could you please post your specific question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Historically, `rspec-mocks` has provided 3 methods for creating a test double: `mock`, `stub` and `double`. In RSpec 3, we’ve removed `mock` and `stub` in favor of just `double`, and built out more features that use the `double` nomenclature (such as verifying doubles — see below).
Of course, while RSpec 3 no longer provides `mock` and `stub` aliases of `double`, it’s easy to define these aliases on your own if you’d like to keep using them." [(source)](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#removed__and__aliases_of_)

Hence, you can just change `stub` calls to `double`:

```
RSpec.describe Teacher do
  it 'stores assignments' do
    student = double
    assignment = double
    subject.submit_assignment(student, assignment)
    expect(subject.assignment_for_student(student)).to eq(assignment)
  end
end
```